# Set flag from table1 to true if relation to table2 exists

Tags: mysql

I guess this is a no-brainer, but somehow I can't manage it right now.

Basically I have a table albums and a table artists, and I want to update artists' `is_composer` and `is_interpreter` flag based on if a relation to album's adequate field exists. (Fiddle with demo schema: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/129a9)

I tried doing an update with a subquery that selected the id's, but that seems to be very very slow. Then I tried by doing it by utilising joins, group by, and having, but at least group by is not usable when doing an update statement.

If someone could point me into the right direction, that would be nice!

Comment: Can you update your SQL Fiddle so that it has relations between the tables? Not much use at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, you're right! Updated the fiddle, hope it's clear now.

Comment: Use `UPDATE` with `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UPDATE` with `LEFT JOIN`

```
UPDATE artists AS a
LEFT JOIN albums AS ai ON ai.interpreter = a.id
LEFT JOIN albums AS ac ON ac.composer = a.id
SET a.is_interpreter = ai.id IS NOT NULL,
    a.is_composer = ac.id IS NOT NULL
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/049628/1)

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work! However, On very big datasets, I get a "Lock wait timeout exceeded", so I have to figure out this as well.

Comment: Do you really need to store this value in the table? It might be better to create a view that looks it up when needed for a specific artist.